# Plugin Create Pre-Operation add related entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

So when an entity is created, I want to search for some other entities and relate them.  However I get a not-exists error if I update the other entities with the entity ref of the newly created one, and that makes sense because it's PRE create.

So I updated it like so thinking this would do the trick, but I'm getting an "unknown error" from somewhere deep in the heart of CRM outside of my control:

```cs
var newEntity = (Entity)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"];
var allUnits = localContext.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(....); //grabs the units that will be used

newEntity.RelatedEntities.Add(new Relationship("ntcp_equipment_unit"), new EntityCollection(allUnits.Entities));
```

Result:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 occurred
Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.dll
Additional information: An unexpected error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your error is, but I would change the plugin to be Create, Post-Operation.  It's still within the database transaction, but now the Target will exist so attempting to add the relationship will succeed rather than fail.

Comment: The Visual Studio xml file that describes registration has the post operation named "PostOutsideTransaction" so I assumed it was outside of the transaction.  However, forcing an error does appear to be rolling back.

Comment: @LameCoder I'm wondering if that was referring to the CRM 4.0 plugin registration?  CRM 2011 is validation out side of transaction, and pre and post, both in the transaction scope